# Weird bug in Devise path after sign in with /admins/sign_in rather than /admins

Tags: authentication, ruby-on-rails-plugins, devise

Im using devise right now and im authenticating with admins and users (two separate types of login). Everything works fine if I go to .../admins and .../users. However, when I go to the url /admins/sign_in, after I sign in it auto redirects me back to the homepage instead of the /admins page like I want. Is there a way for me to redirect it after the /sign_in url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `routes.rb` make sure you include this named paths.

```
map.user_root '/users/edit', :controller => 'users', :action => "edit"
map.admin_root '/admin/edit', :controller => 'users', :action => "edit"
```

I do this so it redirects to the uses settings.

## Update

I'm still on 2.3.8 so for rails 3 you will need to use this:

```
root :to => "home"
```

You can find it here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

## Update

Actually the first code I posted should work for all versions of rails. And just listing root by itself is the default for all devise resources.

Comment: What is the rails 3 version of this? I tried admin_root to: "admin#edit" and it didnt work

Comment: I get this error when I try to do your code

`block in <top (required)>': undefined local variable or method `map' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper:0x00000100bba7a0> (NameError)

Comment: Try taking out map.user_root and just use user_root. If that doesn't work you will need to research rails 3 routes.

Comment: Rails 3 doesn't use map in routes.rb anymore, you should be able to use something like: match "user_root" => "users#edit"

Answer (score 0):

When you log in devise will run the method `after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)` to determine where to go, by default this method will look for an admin_root path and if that doesn't exist it will redirect users to the root path.  Another option would be to over write this method.  Please take a look at my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839004/devise-override-redirect-after-form-submit/4840048#4840048) for more details.

For more information take a look at the [devise documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in).