# Rails devise 1.3.4 confirmable

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, confirmation

I use devise with client side validations and have set the confirmable option.

When I sign up, the mail is sent, but it seems like the controller is unable to see that the account has not been confirmed and tries to sign in.

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-05-24 14:41:47 +0200
  Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
Completed   in 156ms


Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-05-24 14:41:47 +0200
  Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  SQL (3.5ms)   SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod), d.adsrc, a.attnotnull
 FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
 ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
 WHERE a.attrelid = '"users"'::regclass
 AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
 ORDER BY a.attnum

Rendered devise/shared/_links.erb (23.5ms)
Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (92.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 646ms (Views: 117.4ms | ActiveRecord: 3.5ms)
```

Any idea where to look ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a configuration in initializers/devise.rb:

```
  # The time you want to give your user to confirm his account. During this time
  # he will be able to access your application without confirming. Default is 0.days
  # When confirm_within is zero, the user won't be able to sign in without confirming.
  # You can use this to let your user access some features of your application
  # without confirming the account, but blocking it after a certain period
  # (ie 2 days).
  config.confirm_within = 2.days
```

Probably this is the reason it tries to sign in after registration, and logs in the user if it has been set to some value.

Comment: I tried to force it to 0 but I still have the problem. I don't know if I could put a debugger point somewhere to see what's happening.

Comment: What's the problem you are facing? It tries to login and is unable to login because confirmable is set to 0 days. That's the default behaviour I suppose.
Or do you want it to login automatically and user can verify later?

Comment: As the user finishes subscribing, devise tries to log in but it fails since the email is not confirmed. So the user is not informed that he needs to check his emails, and he has an irrelevant error message on the signup page. I'd rather have him redirected to a specific page after succesfull registration telling him to check his emails.

Comment: Meaning: the user is redirected and he gets the :unauthenticated failure whereas I'd rather have the :unconfirmed failure or a specific web page.

Comment: The default notice is: "You have signed up successfully. However, we could not sign you in because your account is unconfirmed." You are getting the failure message probably because you have set your root to (in routes.rb) some page that requires the user to be logged in. It tries to redirect to that page (By default devise redirects to root) and the error message is displayed.

Comment: You're right, I had set the default root to an authenticate page.

Comment: I think I just had to use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839004/devise-override-redirect-after-form-submit) to redirect to a specific page. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yes you can use that or the devise wiki has a number of solutions to the redirect related customizations: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki