# Devise redirects to root_path after successful form submit on edit page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I use devise. After I update my account settings on the "/edit" page (views/devise/registrations/edit.html.erb) by clicking the submit button, it redirects me to the home page with a flash alert: "You updated your account successfully.".

Is there a way to modify this or overwrite the devise's redirect?

Comment: googled 'rails overwrite devise redirect', first result was this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839004/devise-override-redirect-after-form-submit

Comment: found that as well. didnt work. maybe i did something wrong.. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override update action of devise registration controller for this.

```
def update
  set_flash_message :notice, :"message here" if is_flashing_format?
  session[:user_return_to] = url
  super  
end
```

Devise take all the flash messages from config/locales/en.yml . You can also override that in your rails app. format below :

```
en:
  devise:
    registrations:
      destroyed: "my custom message." 
      updated: "my custom message"
```

Comment: Not sure where I place this update action. I did place it into registrations_controller.rb that inherits from Devise::RegistrationsController. Is that correct?

Comment: yes like this. under app/controllers/devise/.........


   class Devise::RegistrationsController < DeviseController
      def update
        set_flash_message :notice, :"message here" if is_flashing_format?
        session[:user_return_to] = url
        super  
      end
    end

Comment: also had to include this in my routes.rb: devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: 'registrations' }

Comment: Yes I forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 3):

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  protected

  def after_update_path_for(resource)
    user_path(resource)
  end

end
```

info: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Customize-the-redirect-after-a-user-edits-their-profile

in-case you have redirect during sign-in you have make changes in `ApplicationController`

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
 path
end
```

Comment: So I have to create a registrations_controller.rb file and place this in?

Comment: yes and make sure it inherits from `Devise::RegistrationsController`